# Fill array with scanf in C (last 5 entered numbers need to be printed)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, scanf

I am having a problem with a school-assignment as shown below:

"write a program that'll repeatedly ask a user for a number and if the user's input is 0, and the loop ends, print the last 5 numbers in an array. If there are less than 5 scanned numbers, the unused values must be 0"

It should look something like this:

[image: click here for the image]

**this is my code:**

```
int main()
{
int i, array[4] = {};

while(1)
{
    printf("Next number: <0 = quit>: ");
    scanf("%i", &i);

    if(i!=0)
    {
        array[0] = array[1];
        array[1] = array[2];
        array[2] = array[3];
        array[3] = array[4];
        array[4] = i;
    }

    else
        break;
}

for(i=0; i<=4; i++)
{
    printf("Number %i is: %i\n", i+1, array[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

but when I print the numbers, the last number **( array[4] )** is 0.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you declare an array as `array[4]` it will have 4 numbers in it and the **last index** in it will be **3** not 4. Declare your array as `array[5]`

Comment: `array[4] = {}` won't compile in C, IIRC, although it would in C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are declaring an array of length 4 here:

```
int i, array[4] = {};
```

This array will then have index from 0 to 3, so you should never try to access
`array[4]`, which will result in undefined behaviour

Comment: @arnofrederiks, If you are new to this you got a bunch of reputation for that answer.  Good job!!